How to show a loading indicator with Blazor QuickGrid
The QuickGrid component in Blazor takes an IQueryable object which is defered so the execution of the query is done inside the QuickGrid
How can I display a loading indicator while the QuickGrid does its magic?
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid
<QuickGrid  Items="results" />

private IQueryable results{ get;set;}
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
     results = ActivityService.GetActivities();
}

thanks
In the animation below you can see that a display message is showed for 1 sec before the quickgrid show the columns (If I add a Task.Delay(1000). but I still have to wait for the data to load without a display message


@if (results== null){<p><em>Loading...</em></p>}else{ <QuickGrid  Items="results" /> }  Do you think this is some what you want? Or you want to know whether there's any built-in configuration for QuickGrid  to enable loading?

We have MS document for QuickGrid component but I didn't  find built-in properties for enabling loading.

You will have to use QuickGrid's ItemsProvider

It isn't built into DataGrid and I don't see any simple way to detect the state of the internal iteration of the provided IQueryable.
You will need to customize the code.  I'll quote the documentation below.

QuickGrid isn't intended to replace advanced datagrid components such
as those from commercial component vendors. Instead, the purpose is:

To provide a convenient, simple, and flexible datagrid component for Blazor developers with the most common needs
To provide a reference architecture and performance baseline for anyone building Blazor datagrid components. Feel free to build on
this, or simply copy code from it.

It's not a goal to add all the features that full-blown commercial
grids tend to have, for example hierarchical rows, drag-to-reorder
columns, or Excel-like range selections. If you need those, continue
using commercial grids or other open-source libraries. Currently we're
only adding the most core grid functionality and things needed for the
key fundamentals.


Alternatively, you can use QuickGrid's ItemsProvider

@Liero -  Agree that in most cases that's a better way of using QuickGrid, but I don't think it solves the "loading" problem for a slow data fetch and iteration.

Why not? In ItemsProvider callback you know the fetch operation start and end

Agree with MrC, the issue OP reported is clearly within the animation. The results is not null as the grid title has shown and the issue is that some extra time is paid for rows to be rendered. We don't know when the rows are completely rendered because QuickGrid doesn't provide such a event.

Agree you can probably rig up (external to the QuickGrid) some form of loading message.

And what OP wants to get is a loading indicator for both result is null and result is not null but rows are not completely rendered. Per my test, OnAfterRenderAsync might be a workaround. And maybe there shall be some other custom solution.

You didn't say what render mode you're using, but if you're using SSR then I think you can stream the results.
Note: I haven't created a test to verify what I'm about to say, and I'm still learning this stuff myself.
That said, what I think what's happening is that...

when OnInitializedAsync completes your page is rerendered with non-null results.
QuickGrid re-renders itself, but the queryable provides results slowly, so it takes some time.
When QuickGrid rendering is complete you see the results in your page, but you dont see any results until QuickGrid has rendered the entire table.

But if you're using SSR I *think you can change that by putting this at the top of your page...
@attribute [StreamRendering]
This will cause the DOM elements rendered on the server to stream to the client as they're rendered.
The result should be that the first row should display quickly, negating the need for a loading indicator at this point.
More rows are displayed as they are rendered.

I am using Blazor server and have eInteractiveServer enabled on the whole app

Had the exact same problem, datasource object becomes not null before entirely loading the data, resulting in delay to load with no "Loading ..." warning. This can be very annoying to the end user (thinking nothing is happening).
This code did the magic for me:
private bool Busy = true;

private POCdbContext? Context { get; set; }

private List<Customer> CustomerList { get; set; } = new List<Customer>();

IQueryable<Customer>? Customers { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var task = GetData();

        await task.ContinueWith(r =>
        {
            if (r.IsCompleted)
            {
                var result = r.Result;

                Dispatcher.CreateDefault().InvokeAsync(() =>
                {
                    // do stuff here
                    Busy = false;
                    // Refresh UI
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

public async Task<List<Customer>> GetData()
{
    List<Customer> customers;

    Context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();

    customers = await Context.Customers.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(TitleFilter)).ToListAsync();

    CustomerList = customers;

    Customers = CustomerList.AsQueryable();

    return customers;
}

bool Busy is the flag that controls wether QuickGrid component renders or not (standard if statement in the html section of razor page -ommited for brevity-). Page rendermode is InteractiveServer.
Adapted the original code by @Surinder Singh InThisAnswer
Hope this helps, took me a long time to find this.
UPDATE: Lol, turns out I overcomplicated things. While the above code works fine, found a way simpler solution: just add at the top of the razor page the StreamRendering attribute
@attribute [StreamRendering]

The rendering logic stays the same, an if statement that renders "loading data..." label if a property (that contains the data) is null and the data table if it is not null

I am pretty new at this, maybe this can help you out, this is the way I did it.
You can use a Modal Component, while loading, display the Modal until quickGrid is loaded
Make the Modal component dynamic
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade show" id="exampleModalLive" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLiveLabel" aria-model="true" role="dialog" style="display:block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable @SizeClass">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">@Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick="OnCancelClick"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @ChildContent
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" @onclick="OnCancelClick">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnActionButtonClick">@ActionButtonText</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ModalSize Size { get; set; } = ModalSize.Default;

    [Parameter]
    public string ActionButtonText { get; set; } = "Ok";

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnActionButtonClick { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnCancelClick { get; set; }

 
    private string SizeClass => Size switch
    {
        ModalSize.Small => "modal-sm",
        ModalSize.Default => "",
        ModalSize.Large => "modal-lg",
        ModalSize.ExtraLarge => "modal-xl",
        _ => ""
    };

}

Call the Modal in your .Razor Page
@if(_showModal)
 {
<Modal Title="String" ActionButtonText="Ok" Size="ModalSize.Large"
    OnActionButtonClick="() => _showModal = false"
    OnCancelClick="() => _showModal = false">
    
    @foreach (var d in _viewingData)
    {
        <div class="mb-3 shadow p-3 border border-start border-sucess">
            @d.Text
        </div>
    }

</Modal>
}

Make the AppState.ShowLoader("Loading Data Please standby") call when OnInitialize in Razor Component Showing the Grid
private bool _isBusy = false;
private string? _errroMessage;
   
private async Task TaskAsync()
 {
    _error = null;
    _isBusy = true;

    try
    {
        AppState.ShowLoader("Loading Data");
        var apiResponse = await AuthAPI.TaskAsync(_model);

        if (!apiResponse.IsSuccess)
        {
            _error = apiResponse.ErrorMessage;
            return;
        }
        _showSuccessAlert = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _error = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        _isBusy = false;
        AppState.HideLoader();
    }
}

Create AppState
namespace NameSpace.Web.ApplicationState
{
    public class AppState : IAppState
    {
        public string? LoadingText { get; private set; }

        public event Action? OnToggleLoader;
        public event Action<string>? OnShowError;

        public void HideLoader()
        {
            LoadingText = null;
            OnToggleLoader?.Invoke();
        }

        public void ShowLoader(string loadingText)
        {
            LoadingText = loadingText;
            OnToggleLoader?.Invoke();
        }

        public void ShowError(string errorText) =>
        OnShowError?.Invoke(errorText);
    }
}

Create Interface from AppState
 public interface IAppState
 {
      string? LoadingText { get; }
      void ShowLoader(string loadingText);
      void HideLoader();
      event Action? OnToggleLoader;
      void ShowError(string errorText);
  }

Inject IAppState into the Razor component
@inject IAppSate AppState

Make sure to register
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAppState, AppState>();

